# Active Pen support in Linux for HP X360

Tags: hp, touchscreen, input-method

i have recently bought a HP Pavilion x360 14-ba017ng with only Windows atm, but i want to install a Linux Distribution on this notebook. 
My only concern is that this notebook has active pen, tablet mode and touch and if this works correctly.

I already did some research but most posts and information i found are at least a year old.

So my questions are,

what distribution would you people prefer for active pen input and touchscreen/table mode?

are there any actual known problems with this kind of inputmethods?

Best Regards :)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I am not sure how similar the Pavilion x360 is to the Spectre. Touch, Pen, and Tilt work on the HP Spectre x360 15t with Intel On-Board Graphics and NVIDIA GeForce GPU. I suggest creating a Live ISO, booting into it, and testing your hardware without installing Ubuntu. (See https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0). This test will quickly answer if your hardware works with Ubuntu. But if it doesn't work in this quick test, you may just have to work a little harder to get everything running.

Answer (score 3):

I have just received my new Asus Zenbook Flip and I'm about to install Ubuntu 17.10, so I'll report back here on my success / lack thereof.

You asked 4 months ago, did you learn anything yourself about this in the meantime?

Update: I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and the pen works 100%.

Comment: what i learned was that if you wan't to know it, install it..... most stuff i found says "it's different on every machine / manufacturer .....

Answer (score -1):

HP support is garbage. Touch screen works out of the box and tilt driver was promised by AMD since August. General compatibility, particularly around ACPI though is horrible.